# Why are many .NET core assemblies built targeting .NET standard?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-standard

As an example, the NuGet Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestral targets .NETStandard. I understand that this is probably a practical choice, as now a .NET framework/Xamerin application can use this package. However it therefore seems an odd choice of name by Microsoft to include the word NetCore in the package.

If I reference this package from my .NET Full framework web api, my API is strictly speaking a .NET full framework API even though it is being served by the open source ".NET core" web server Kestral.

Anyone know why Microsoft went with this nomenclature, or I have misunderstood something ?

Comment: core usually means it is has no platform dependencies.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard may be helpful to you.

Comment: Its to be noted here, this is only true for (ASP).NET Core 2.x. [ASP.NET Core 3.0 will only run on .NET Core](https://github.com/aspnet/Announcements/issues/324).

Answer (score 3):

ASP.NET Core is not the same as .NET Core. ASP.NET Core can be run on the full framework also (currently). The package name refers to this, not to .NET Core.

And why wouldn’t any package target .NET Standard if they can? It will allow wider use than targeting only a certain subset.

Answer (score 1):

As an addition to Sami Kuhmonen's answer:

Taken from [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard)

> The .NET Standard is a formal specification of .NET APIs that are intended to be available on all .NET implementations. The motivation behind the .NET Standard is establishing greater uniformity in the .NET ecosystem. ECMA 335 continues to establish uniformity for .NET implementation behavior, but there's no similar spec for the .NET Base Class Libraries (BCL) for .NET library implementations.
>
> The .NET Standard enables the following key scenarios:
>
> - Defines uniform set of BCL APIs for all .NET implementations to implement, independent of workload.
> - Enables developers to produce portable libraries that are usable across .NET implementations, using this same set of APIs.
> - Reduces or even eliminates conditional compilation of shared source due to .NET APIs, only for OS APIs.

This means anything targeting .NET Standard can run on any machine, as long as it has a framework that implements the standard it targets. For instance, anything targeting  .NET Standard 2.0 can run on a machine with any of these framework versions (or higher):

- .NET Core 2
- .NET Framework 4.6.1
- Mono 5.4
- Xamarin iOS 10.14
- Xamarin Mac 3.8
- Xamarin Android 8.0
- Universal Windows Platform 10.0.16299
- Unity 2018.1